# Simple login script multiple users from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, login-script

I have problem with my login script in Python 3.5.2.

The problem with my code is that only first user in file **users.txt** can pass login. Second and third users get "Wrong username/password" message. What am I missing here ?

Data in users.txt are formated like this:

**Name|Surname|Role|ID|Username|Password**

John|Johnson|Director|1|admin|admin

Mike|Madson|CFO|2|mike|mike

Problem is only John pass login and I need Mike as well.

```
def check():

    username = str(input("Username: "))
    password = str(input("Password: "))

    f = open("users.txt", "r")
    file_content = f.read()
    users = file_content.split("\n")
    for user in users:
        user_array = user.split("|")
        uname = user_array[4]
        pword = user_array[5]
        if uname == username and pword == password:
            print("Hello " + user_array[1] + ".")
            print("You are logged in as: " + user_array[2] + ".")
            main_menu()
        else:
            print("Wrong username/password.")
            print("Try again!\n\n")
            check()
check()
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic was all wrong. You need something like that:

```
def check():
    # You need to read it only once, not every loop
    users = open("users.txt").read().split("\n")
    for i in range(len(users)): users[i] = users[i].split("|")

    # Now what you want is to loop infinitely
    # until you get correct username/password
    # instead of recursive calling this
    # function over and over again
    while True:
        username = str(input("Username: "))
        password = str(input("Password: "))

        for user in users:
            uname = user[4]
            pword = user[5]

            if uname == username and pword == password:
                print("Hello " + user[1] + ".")
                print("You are logged in as: " + user[2] + ".")
                main_menu()

        # If none of the records matched the input
        print("Wrong username/password.")
        print("Try again!\n\n")

check()
```

Comment: I've tried but I get NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: xrange was renamed to range in python 3 and they eliminated the xrange function. it just returns a generator instead of a list in python 3

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the line

```
if uname == username and pword == password:
```

Because you ask the user for their username and password in the beginning of the function, and I assume they enter "admin" and "admin", this check is only going to pass for that combination. You should either include the `input` requests in the for loop or restructure this to work better.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the text file, john will be first, so when your using the if statment to compare if the username and password is a match, you are comapring with only the first line of the text file. So when you enter mike, it will compae with john on the text file, from what i understand, that is where u went wrong